# GWT Internationalization for dynamically generated content

Tags: gwt, internationalization

For a majority of my app I am able to use the recommended internationalization techniques as laid out in https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n (mainly the UIBinder approach).

I am currently using a single widget that takes in an object and displays its attributes/fields dynamically and therefore am unable to use UIBinder and the aforementioned internationalization technique.

Will I just need to change my design and create multiple widgets for each type of object I wish to display or is there an established internationalization technique I have yet to find??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to re-read the the Dev Guide from the section titled [Dynamic String Internationalization](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18n#DevGuideDynamicStringInternationalization).

The approach means you need to code for locale support. We have done this using [Dictionary](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html) class. The trick to provide locale support is to have a dictionary for each locale.

**Step 1-**
Ensure you use locale concepts of GWT module.gwt.xml with cookie. Ensure cookie GWT_LOCALE is set before gwt application loads.

```
<extend-property name="locale" values="en,ar,de" />
<set-property name="locale" value="en" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
<set-configuration-property name="locale.cookie" value="GWT_LOCALE" />
<set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent" value="Y" />
```

**Step 2-**
Load WidgetMessages.js upfront using html script tags or Use RequestBuilder if you wish to fetch this lazily on demand. Contents of WidgetMessages.js

```
var widget_messages_en = {
    "today" : "Today",
    "now" : "Now"
};

var widget_messages_ar= {
    "today"  : "۷ڤدجچ",
    "now"  : "چڤت"
}

var widget_messages_de= { 
    "today"  : "Today",
    "now"  : "Now"
}
```

**Step 3-** Process and load the dictionaries into a local hashmap.

```
    private static Map<String, Dictionary> I18N_DICTIONARIES = new HashMap<String, Dictionary>();

    private static Dictionary createDictionary( String dictionaryName)
    {
            String moduleId = dictionaryName + "_messages_" + LocaleInfo.getCurrentLocale().getLocaleName();
            Dictionary dictionary = Dictionary.getDictionary( moduleId );
            I18N_DICTIONARIES.put( dictionaryName, dictionary );
            return dictionary;
    }

    public static String getI18NString(String dictionaryName, String stringToInternationalize )
    {
        Dictionary dictionary = I18N_DICTIONARIES.get( dictionaryName);
        if ( dictionary == null )
        {
            dictionary = createDictionary( dictionaryName);
        }
        String i18string = null;
        if ( dictionary == null )
            return stringToInternationalize;
        try
        {
            i18string = dictionary.get( stringToInternationalize );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
        }
        return i18string;
    }
```

**Note** - YOU CAN TRY Several variations of the above approach to process strings to i18nstrings and use them on widgets....

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the Dictionary class? It should meet your needs unless your labels need to be locale sensitive 
http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Dictionary.html